# How to send an object inside a Coroutine Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm starting to use coroutines with Kotlin, I want to pass as a parameter an object from the fragment, but I still haven't understood well how this object could happen to this coroutine, I'll really be grateful for your help

```
val addObject: LiveData<Object> = liveData {
    emit(Result.loading())
    try {
        emit(Result.success(fetchUser()))
    } catch(ioException: Exception) {
        emit(Result.error(ioException))
    }
}
```

From my fragment I would have to send my object and then be able to observe it

```
productViewModel.addObject(Object).observe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant pass an object in a parameter that does not even make sense.

what you probably want to be doing is something like this

ViewModel

```
private val _liveData: MutableLiveData<Object> = MutableLiveData()
val liveData:LiveData<Object>
    get() = _liveData

fun addObject(myObject:Object){
    // do work here
    emit(someData)
}
```

Or even just

```
fun addObject(myObject:Object):LiveData<Object>{
    val liveData: MutableLiveData<Object> = MutableLiveData()
    viewModelScope.launch {
        //do work then emit back
        liveData.postValue(it)
    }
    return liveData
}
```

Activity

```
viewModel.liveData.observe(this, Observer{
    
})

viewModel.addObject(myObject)
```

Or for the second example

```
viewModel.addObject(myObject).observe(this, Observer{
    
})
```